# Where is Maffee's girlfriend?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, billions

Where is *Maffee*'s girlfriend *Deb Kawi* (Axe's secretary) from 1st and 2nd seasons of Billions? 
As I recall her disappearance never explained.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*In Universe*

We don't know.

*Out of Universe*

The actress, [**Ilfenesh Hadera**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3947644/) scored a part in the [Baywatch](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1469304/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_5) movie and then moved on to other series, notably *She's Gotta Have it* and, perhaps more importantly, a starring role in [*Deception*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6461812/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_1)

Comment: It's sad that deception was cancelled, though not being one of realistic,genius shows, but I liked it